# Whenever a property or function of `Vue instance` changes , some of the methods gets executed. Please explain this behavior

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

https://jsfiddle.net/Arpan_Banerjee7/bfnL50vs/1/

I have shared a link of JSFiddle, you can see the demo there.
Whenever you `mousemove` over the last paragraph, the coordinates changes and it gets logged as expected.

**But I have noticed a rather strange behavior.**

I noticed that whenever the function `changeCoordinates()` is executed the other two functions within the method also gets executed--`randomNumber()` and `testFunction()`.

*Please open the dev tools>console to see the logs of `testFunction()`.*

Does all the methods  execute whenever any of the methods executes?

Can you please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

```
In comparison, a method invocation will always run the function whenever a re-render happens.
```

So whenever your X or y values change a re-render is invoked on the page and the methods are run, since they are called from the template.

In your case it seems that "all method" are run, but that is simply because all methods are present in the template. Methods only run when explicitly activated, either by code in another method or by invocation from the template.